# Why is the loop endless?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, inputstream, infinite-loop

I'm doing some homework and trying to make it safe from character input but somehow writing a character inside still breaks it because it makes the loop infinite. Can anyone suggest a way to fix it? Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    srand( time( NULL ) );

    int given = 0;
    int imaginarynum = ( std::rand() % 99 ) + 1;
    int tries = 0;

    std::cout << "Hello! We'regoing to play an easy game! I'm goinng to think of a number between 1-100 and you'll have to guess it! " << std::endl;
    std::cout << given << " "<< imaginarynum;

    while(given < imaginarynum || given > imaginarynum)
    {
        std::cin >> given;
        bool error = std::cin.fail();
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.sync();

        while(error != false)
        {
            std::cout << "That's not a number!" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> given;
            bool error = std::cin.fail();
            std::cin.clear();
        }

        if (given < imaginarynum)
        {
            std::cout << "I thought of a bigger number! " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Guess again!" << std::endl;
            tries = tries + 1;
        }else if (given > imaginarynum)
        {
            std::cout << "I thought of a smaller number! " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Guess again!" << std::endl;
            tries = tries + 1;
        }
        else
        {`enter code here`
            tries = tries + 1;
            std::cout << "Good job! " << std::endl << "It took you: " << tries << " Tries!";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless user enters exactly `imaginarynum`, this will not end.

Comment: `while (given != imaginarynum)` would be more readable. If that's what you meant to do...

Comment: Naming your variable `imaginarynum` is sort of misleading, as it does not denote an [imaginary number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number), denoted in C++ by using the [complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex) header

Comment: @Martin that doesn't work, it still crashes and burns when something that's not a number is entered.

Comment: What do you mean by _"writing a character inside"_? Give clear, precise reproduction steps to describe your problem.

Comment: @Martin It's an obvious requirement of the task, and the code has constructs to perform that.

Comment: @Martin right in the first sentence: "I'm doing some homework and trying to make it **safe from character input**"

Comment: I'm guessing OP considers the word "character" to mean "non-digit character" in this context. Though they should really be clearer.

Comment: @Martin `enter code here` is a placeholder from SO's question formatting tools that the OP left in by mistake. It wouldn't have been in the original code.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using two variables `error`

```
    while(error != false)
    {
        std::cout << "That's not a number!" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> given;
        bool error = std::cin.fail();
        std::cin.clear();
    }
```

Within the loop you declared a new variable. Substitute the declaration for an assignment statement

```
    while(error != false)
    {
        std::cout << "That's not a number!" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> given;
        error = std::cin.fail();
        std::cin.clear();
    }
```

And the second problem is that you need to clear the buffer. For example

```
#include <limits>

//...

std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

The loop will look the following way

```
    #include <limits>

    //...

    while(error != false)
    {
        std::cout << "That's not a number!" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> given;
        error = std::cin.fail();
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend cranking the error level up to maximum.  Some compilers will warn that the inner variable hides the outer one.

Comment: Warning level, not error level. Maximum is overkill but `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` is good.